# What's the name of this type of navigation?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, terminology

I want to know whats the name of the navigation of these sites bellow:

- http://www.visitsuffolk.com
- http://www.ehow.com.br
- http://www.blogdoplaneta.com

I searched for 'responsive grid', but its refers to all site, and its not what i want. I want to know the name of the navigation of the news, that adjust in a animation to screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the way the components re-position themselves when the screen-size changed then the word you are looking for is `relayout`. The layout pattern is called masonry or cell based layout.

There are many plugins that let you implement such layouts. See [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Comment: That is exactly what i was talkin about. Thank you!

Comment: It's colloquially referred to as "Metro" style Navigation, since Microsoft most recently popularized it. Personally, I think it has far too much in common with the early 2000s mystery meat navigation for my tastes. Your navigation is supposed to effectively impart information to the end user, not entertain them. Leave the entertainment to your site content. Any time you force the end user guess, wait, or iterate you lose engagement.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it called an [off-canvas navigation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website-2/), a [slideout menu](http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns), [slideout navigation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path), and simply a [responsive navigation](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/). It's built into [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which is one of the most popular responsive frameworks, so you'll see more of it as more sites implement responsive design.

Comment: hm I guess your answers refers to the style of menu, and I wanted to know not the menu's name, but the navigation of the news that adjust in the grid. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand what you're asking about. There's an article on how to do that here (called Animated Media Queries): http://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/. Check out the demo: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/full/tynas and watch the light blue "Search" box move positions slowly. The grid is using a responsive design with elements changing positions based on window width; the repositioning is animated with CSS Transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the type of navigation for the sites you listed above is "Category Navigation. You can read more about different types of navigation [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/11/navigation-patterns-for-ten-common-types-of-websites/) and also another example of "Category Navigation" which relates to it [example](http://www.whatisblik.com/shop/explore?p=2). Hope this helped.